# LTC1153 current trip off IC

Tags: current, current-limiting

I am using an LTC1153 IC, with an IRLML6346 MOSFET.
I am supplying a 3.3V rail. Now, the output
is being fed to an arduino board and the supply works. 
The Gate pin gives out about 7V (in conformance of the graph in the datasheet).

Thwe MOSFET is on and the current is supplied.
But, when I make a short circuit the Gate voltage is 2V and hence the MOSFET is still on.
The sense resistor is 1 Ohm and hence should be designed to shut out or turn off when the current is greater than 100mAmps(with the 100mV drop theory).
The Schematic is as shown below. -

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to provide the [LTC1153](http://www.linear.com/docs/2817) with a *minimum* of 4.5V. With a 3.3V supply, operation of the part will be indeterminate.

See page 2 of the datasheet.

You can find parts that have a lower operating voltage at [This link](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Surge_Stopper,_Overvoltage_*_Overcurrent_Protection#!cols_1030,2218,2217,1031,1153,1367,1043,1132!s_1132,0!gtd_) - page is sorted by Vs range.